# How to copy all files with names matching a pattern in one system call that is i dont want to issue multiple File.copy()

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to copy and delete files matching specified name pattern in one system command.
Is it possible to do it?
I dont want to use a for loop

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a choice. There isn't a facility to copy a directory in the .NET API. You will have to iterate through the matched files yourself and copy them to the right location.